# found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)

Tags: android, firebase, androidx

I try to add firebase-core:17.0.0 in dependency but it display this error. **I don't want to my code migrate into androidX** :-

> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.package-info found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$ParcelException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$FieldBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$InputBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
>   Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelize found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

but when i add this lines run perfect :-

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}
```

but when i add these lines i **can't access Firebase Analytics** package.
How can i solve it?

Comment: Can you show me your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to this error.

First, remove this code from your build.gradle file

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}
```

Here you use the AndroidX supported library in your project. That's why they give you this kind of error.

Please first check firebase blog and confirm the usage library in your project is supported AndroidX. If yes then reduce that library version.